# Проблема сохранения данных в Qt

Tags: qt5, qtcreator

У меня есть приложение в `Qt`, подскажите чем мне воспользоваться, если хочу, что бы при выходе из приложения, данные которые я храню в объекте класса, на пример `MyData`,сохранились. И когда запускаем  приложение вновь данные уже были в приложении бы сохраненные.

Comment: ну еслми это настройки или какието данные которые постонянно нужно хранить и от них завист дальнейшая работу , то в Qt Усть такая штука QSettings она позволяет сохранять конфиги и вообще любые данные перед завершением работы, как работатье с QSetting изложно в стандартной справке и можете глянуть [тут](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QSettings)

Comment: Записывайте ваши данные, используя `QSettings`, или просто в файлы, или в БД (например `sqlite`).